# RubyとRailsをインストール後、gem puma -v '3.11.3'のインストール方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

RubyとRailsをインストール後、確認すると以下の表示がありました。

```
>ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x64-mingw32]
>rails -v
Rails 5.1.6
```

そして　snsというアプリ作成のため下記の入力をしました。

```
rails new sns
```

上記の処理途中で下記のエラーが出ます。

```
To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/puma-3.11.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.3 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/puma-3.11.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing puma (3.11.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install puma -v '3.11.3'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
puma
```

この場合、puma -v '3.11.3'をインストールするためには下記の入力でいいのでしょうか？
(インストールする場所等の指定がいるのでしょうか?)

```
gem install puma -v '3.11.3'
```

初心者でよくわかりません。宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

はい、ひとまずはそれを行ってみてください。エラーメッセージが言っているのは次の2点です。

- 依存パッケージの puma がインストールできなかったので、`gem install puma -v '3.11.3` を実行して成功するか試して欲しい。
- インストールできなかった際のログを `C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/puma-3.11.3/mkmf.log` に保存したので、失敗の理由が知りたい場合はこのファイルを見て欲しい。

というわけで、`gem install puma -v '3.11.3'` をひとまず実行してみて成功すればそれで良し、それも失敗すれば `mkmf.log` などのログファイルを見て、何が原因なのか探ることになります。

Comment: gem install puma -v '3.11.3'　を実行してエラーが出ます。質問を編集すると長くなるので、後ほど新たに質問します。

Comment: 参考: 続きの質問は[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/42857/19110)。